# Karate: Not able to pass header value extracted from one api response into the request header of another api

Tags: api, automated-tests, karate

**Here I'm storing the value of Etag into variable etag, here the values is printed correctly:**

Given path '/price/v4/quote/',quoteId,'/products'

And request requestPayload

When method POST

- print 'headers:', karate.prevRequest.headers

Then status 200

And def etag = responseHeaders['ETag']

- print etag
  [print]
  ["3"]

**Now I'm passing it to the request header of another api:**

```
* header If-Match = etag
Given path '/price/v4/quote/',quoteId,'/accept'
And request requestPayload
When method PUT
* print 'headers:', karate.prevRequest.headers
Then status 200
* print karate.pretty(response)
```

**But I'm getting following error as the value of etag header comes with regex:**

```
Got invalid quoteVersion for quote 'b25f50bc-0479-4390-b4fe-0620fc6c6139'. quoteVersion '[\"3\"]', actualVersion '3'"}
```

Comment: you seem to be new to stack overflow. please read this and then consider re-writing your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Peter thanks for replying, I'm new to stack overflow, I have tried to rewrite the question in a more presentable way after going through the above content

Comment: really appreciate you taking the feedback, not many people do this here ! I have tried to answer your question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed that `responseHeaders` is a `Map` of `List`s. Refer the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#responseheaders

Try this:

```
And def etag = responseHeaders['ETag'][0]
```

Also we have a better API for headers in the next versions for anyone else coming across this in the future, please refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1962

Comment: Thanks! for your help Peter, it worked, I also went through the links you've shared and they very useful